# Помогите решением простого вопроса по js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать выборочные ссылки потом подключить к ним аякс есть стандартный скрипт работает от части но если кликнуть на link1 и обратно на All то не будет работать хоть и у All больше нету class active как можно решить это?

```
<li class=active><a href='#'>All</a>
<li ><a href='#'>link1</a>
<li ><a href='#'>link2</a>
<li ><a href='#'>link3</a>



jQuery('.tabs ul li[class="active"] a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

});
jQuery('.tabs ul li[class!="active"] a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.tabs ul li[class="active"]').removeClass( "active" );
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
   doajax();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX тут ни при чем.

```
jQuery('.tabs ul li a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!$(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).closest('.tabs').find('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    doajax();
  }
});
```